# How to detect if you need to recreate python virtualenvs?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I know for sure that if system python is updated we need to recreate the `virtualenvs`. Still, I don't know if there are cases which may indicate us that `virtualenvs` may need recreation.

Do you know a more complete list of checks to be done for this?

Please note that I am looking for a way to figure out this that does not include looping across all virtualenvs on a machine. I am only looking for a trigger that is not dependent on individual `virtualenvs`.

Comment: I think, if system python is updated, we don't need to recreate the `virtualenvs`.
Update the packages using `pip install` or if you are using python3 `pip3 install' will help you.
That's all

Comment: The purpose of the virtual environment is to be *independent* of the system  Python. Why would you necessarily need to update the virtual environment in that case? Just because your system moves from (hypothetically) Python 2.7 to Python 3.6 doesn't mean the project being developed in a Python-2.7 virtual environment has (or should).